# How can people in Indonesia use Bitcoins?

Tags: exchanges, alternatives, buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins

Dwolla does not accept me.

So what's the alternative?

How can I for example, withdraw money to rupiah or dollar account in US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try https://www.bitcoin.co.id/ and use IDR.

Or you can find seller / buyer in https://localbitcoins.com/places/570925/jakarta-id/

Answer (score 4):

Indonesia is one of the countries where no Bitcoin exchanges have much reach to just quite yet.

Are international wire transfers a possibility?  If so, most exchanges offer international wire transfers.

About the only payment network that any bitcoin exchanges use that have the ability to interact with Indonesian banks domestically is Payza, but theirs is a method for adding funds from a bank account and not the other way around.

OKPay is a network that might be usable for you.  They have an international prepaid debit card which can be loaded with USDs from your bitcoins.

There are also other digital currencies which might help -- though there are a couple of hops between your bitcoins before you end up with rupiah.  [Aurum X Change](https://www.aurumxchange.com) can be used to cash out to Liberty Reserve, HD-Money, CosmicPay, SolidTrustPay, Global Digital Pay, and G-Gold e-currencies.  If none of those are familiar to you, you might use an intermediary such as [GoldMediator](https://www.goldmediator.com) to eventually get a connection to a bank.

Additionally, there may be a local buyer wondering how to buy bitcoins from within Indonesia.  If there are any hacker spaces, you would probably find someone willing to do a trade with you.

The list of exchanges offering cash out methods can be found here:
 - http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Selling_bitcoins

Comment: The reason I want to use bitcoin is so I do not have to deal with the like of paypal payza and moneybookers I've heard horor stories how they seize money with absolutely no reason under pretext of helping you. Government pretty much grant them monopoly by preventing other trades.

Comment: There aren't any open offers to sell yet but you could list an offer to buy bitcoins:

 - http://localbitcoins.com/postal_code/id/jakarta/#

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin is growing slowly but surely in Indonesia. If you're looking for a secure wallet that provides instant buy/sell in Indonesia, go with https://www.luno.com. You can sell your Bitcoin and withdraw it to Indonesian bank accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ChangeHero](https://changehero.io/id/). They operate there and you can exchange many cryptos without an account.